# Convertir Tiempo a segundos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, método

Tengo que realizar un método que calcule las horas en función de horas, minutos y segundos me dé la conversión de horas a segundos:

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce tres números que serán hora, minutos y segundos");
            Console.ReadLine();

            int conversionHoras()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Calcula las horas en función de los segundos y los minutos, e introduce las horas");
                int horas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                int minutos = horas * 60;
                int segundos = horas * 3600;

                int resultado = horas;
                return resultado;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: en dónde está fallando tu programa?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo no lo sé exactamente, sólo sé que no se me ejecuta el método

Answer (score 4):

```
class Program
{
    int ConversionHoras(int horas, int minutos, int segundos)
    {
        int resultado = (horas * 3600) + (minutos * 60) + segundos;

        return resultado;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Introduce las horas");

        int horas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce los minutos");

        int minutos= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce los segundos");

        int segundos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        int tiempo = conversionHoras(horas, minutos, segundos);

        Console.WriteLine("Tiempo total en segundos: " + tiempo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Primero la **función ConversionHoras** va afuera del **método Main()**, esta función recibe tres parámetros: las horas, los minutos y los segundos. Dentro de esta función se convierten todos los tiempos a segundos multiplicando las **horas** * **3600** ya que una hora tiene **3600** **segundos**, también se multiplican los **minutos** * **60** ya que un minuto tiene **60** **segundos** y los segundos pues se quedan como están. Todos estos cálculos se suman devolviéndose así el total de segundos.

Ahora bien dentro del **método Main**, guardo las horas, minutos y segundos que le voy a pedir al usuario que introduzca y estos datos son los que voy a pasar por parámetros a la función antes descrita. Posteriormente imprimo el resultado.

Comment: estaba creando una respuesta, pero no quería darle la respuesta al problema que estaba haciendo... pero bueno, ya me ganaste, jeje

Comment: bueno igual mira a ver si te sirve

Comment: a lo que iba, es que iba a hacer lo que hiciste, pero sin poner el contenido del método conversionHoras...